# RxJS function that emit last value from one observable then other emit true

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Hellow, I'm trying to create function of observable (OBS) and subject(SUB) that stores last item from OBS, while SUB has F value,
and emit it (and only it) when SUN becomes T

```
   OBS ---a----b----c----d----e----f----g----h-----
   SUB ------F----------T------------F-------T-----
   OUT -----------------c--------------------h-----
```

I tried to solve this with

```
OBS.window(SUB)
        .withLatestFrom(SUB)
        .switchMap(([window, status]) => {

            if(status === F) {
                return window.combineLatest(SUB, (cmd, status) => {
                    if(status === T) {
                        return null;
                    };

                    return cmd;
                }).last((e) => {
                    return !!e;
                })
            }

            return Observable.empty<Command>();
        }).filter((cmd) => {
            return !!cmd;
        })
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: If `SUB` emits two `T`s in a row, should resulting observable still produce the last value received when `SUB` was `F`?

Comment: @SergeyKaravaev, no but it can be fixed with distinctUntilChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like you want something like:

```
SUB
  // Only emit changes in the status
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  // Only forward true values down stream
  .filter(t => t === T)
  // Only emit the latest from OBS when you get a T from SUB
  // Remap it so only cmd is forwarded
  .withLatestFrom(OBS, (_, cmd) => cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found own solution:

```
OBS
    .buffer(SUB)
    .withLatestFrom(SUB)
    .map(([buffer, t]) => {
        if(!buffer || !buffer.length) {
            return null;
        }

        if(t === T) {
            return buffer[buffer.length - 1];
        }

        return null;
    })
    .filter((e) => !!e);
```

this variant has next behavior

```
 ---a----b----c----d----e----f----g----h-----
 ------F----------T------------F-------T-----
 -----------------c--------------------h-----
```

and don't generate output if window between F and T is empty

```
 ---a--------------d----e----f----g----h-----
 ------F----------T------------F-------T-----
 --------------------------------------h-----
```